# Add bibliography to the fancy-CV

Tags: bibliographies

How can I add bibliography to this CV? I used `\printbibsection{}{}` in the `publications section`, but it didn't work.

ShareLaTeX link : [LINK](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59995f7c6080cd3eb1349e81)

Main code:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\header{adrien}{friggeri}
       {social network analyst}


% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{about}
    31 rue Smith
    69002 Lyon
    France
    ~
    \href{mailto:adrien@friggeri.net}{adrien@friggeri.net}
    \href{http://friggeri.net}{http://friggeri.net}
    \href{http://facebook.com/adrien}{fb://adrien}
  \section{languages}
    bilingual french/english
    spanish \& italian notions
  \section{programming}
    {\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} JavaScript
    (ES5, node.js)
    Python, C, OCaml
    CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}

\section{interests}

complex networks, social networks, community detection, community structure,
overlapping communities, information diffusion, viral marketing, social
inference, recommendation, data mining

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {since 2009}
    {Ph.D. {\normalfont candidate in Computer Science}}
    {DNET/INRIA, LIP/ÉNS de Lyon}
    {\emph{A Quantified Theory of Social Cohesion.}}
  \entry
    {2007–2008}
    {M.Sc. magna cum laude}
    {IXXI, École Normale Supérieure de Lyon}
    {Majoring in Computer Science\\
    Specialization in Complex Systems}
  \entry
    {2006–2007}
    {B.Sc. magna cum laude}
    {École Normale Supérieure de Lyon}
    {Majoring in Computer Science}
  \entry
    {2003–2006}
    {Classes Préparatoires aux Grandes Écoles}
    {Lycée Fénelon, Lycée Louis le Grand, Paris}
    {Preparation for national competitive entrance exams to leading French ``grandes écoles'', specializing in mathematics and physics.}
  \entry
    {2003}
    {French Baccalauréat S. with honors}
    {Lycée Louis le Grand, Paris}
    {Specialization in mathematics and physics}
\end{entrylist}

\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {02–07 2009}
    {LIP6/CNRS, Paris}
    {Research Internship.}
    {\emph{Visualization of complex networks.}}
  \entry
    {06–08 2008}
    {ISCPIF/CNRS, Paris}
    {Research Internship.}
    {\emph{Diffusion in the Blogosphere. Happy Flu.}}
  \entry
    {06–08 2007}
    {LIP6/CNRS, Paris}
    {Research Internship.}
    {\emph{Kernels in real world networks.}}
  \entry
    {07–08 2005}
    {\href{http://www.kelkoo.com}{Kelkoo.com}}
    {Summer job.}
    {\emph{Creation of a keyword generator for Google Adwords.}}
  \entry
    {07–08 2004}
    {\href{http://www.monsieurprix.com}{MonsieurPrix.com}}
    {Summer job.}
    {\emph{Development of an e-commerce product indexation spider.}}
\end{entrylist}

\section{applications}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {2012}
    {Who did I forget ?}
    {\href{http://whodidiforget.com}{whodidiforget.com}}
    {Guest list recommendation for Facebook events based on friends already attending the event.}
  \entry
    {2011}
    {Fellows}
    {\href{http://fellows-exp.com}{fellows-exp.com}}
    {Automatic community detection among Facebook Friends in order to validate the \emph{cohesion} measure, creation of friend lists.}
  \entry
    {2008}
    {Happy Flu}
    {\href{http://happyflu.com}{happyflu.com}}
    {Experiment aimed to measure viral spreading of content across the blogosphere.}
\end{entrylist}

\section{publications}


%%% This piece of code has been commented by Karol Kozioł due to biblatex errors. 
% 
%\printbibsection{article}{article in peer-reviewed journal}
%\begin{refsection}
%  \nocite{*}
%  \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type=inproceedings, title={international peer-reviewed conferences/proceedings}, notkeyword={france}, heading=subbibliography]
%\end{refsection}
%\begin{refsection}
%  \nocite{*}
%  \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type=inproceedings, title={local peer-reviewed conferences/proceedings}, keyword={france}, heading=subbibliography]
%\end{refsection}
%\printbibsection{misc}{other publications}
%\printbibsection{report}{research reports}

\end{document}
```

Template:

```
\ProvidesClass{friggeri-cv}[2012/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}

\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FDA333}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{D3A4F9}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FB4485}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{6CE0F1}

\ifdefined\@cv@print
  \colorlet{green}{gray}
  \colorlet{orange}{gray}
  \colorlet{purple}{gray}
  \colorlet{red}{gray}
  \colorlet{blue}{gray}
  \colorlet{fillheader}{white}
  \colorlet{header}{gray}
\else
  \colorlet{fillheader}{gray}
  \colorlet{header}{white}
\fi
\colorlet{textcolor}{gray}
\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%

% \RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
% \RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}
% 
% \newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Helvetica Neue}
% \newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Helvetica Neue UltraLight}
% \newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}
% 
% \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
% \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Helvetica Neue Light}
% 
% \setmathfont{XITS Math}

%%% modified by Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTex use
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont
[BoldFont=texgyreheros-bold.otf,
ItalicFont=texgyreheros-italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=texgyreheros-bolditalic.otf]
{texgyreheros-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Lato-Light.ttf}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{texgyreheros-bold.otf}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont
[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor,
BoldFont=texgyreheros-bold.otf,
ItalicFont=texgyreheros-italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=texgyreheros-bolditalic.otf
]
{texgyreheros-regular.otf}

\setmathfont{texgyreheros-regular.otf}
%%%

%%%%%%%%%%
% Header %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rolefont}{%
  \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\selectfont%
  \thinfont%
  \color{white}%
}

\newcommand{\header}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=4cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{40pt}{72pt}\color{header}%
      {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont  #2}
    };
    \node [anchor=north] at (name.south) {%
      \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\color{header}%
      \thinfont #3%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{2.5cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Structure %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        green\or%
        purple\else%
        headercolor\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  {%
  \large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Side block %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[style=verbose, maxnames=99, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \newunit%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{type}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \small\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
  \ifblank{##3}{}{##3\space}#1%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}
    {}%
}

\newcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsection}
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{chronological}{
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{month}}
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Other tweaks %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[left=6.1cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

Bib file:

```
%% This document is a bibtex export of HAL publication
%% Date of the export : 02/05/2012
%% Criteria : Author : 'friggeri'

%%
%% inria-00490195, version 2
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00490195
%%

@article{friggeri:2011:inria-00490195:2,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Chelius, Guillaume and Fleury, Eric and Fraboulet, Antoine and Mentr{\'e}, France and Lucet, Jean-Christophe},
  TITLE = {{Reconstructing Social Interactions Using an unreliable Wireless Sensor Network}},
  JOURNAL = {{Computer Communications}},
  PUBLISHER = {Elsevier},
  VOLUME = {34},
  NUMBER = {5},
  PAGES = {609--618},
  YEAR = {2011},
  MONTH = Apr,
  KEYWORDS = {complex networks; interaction networks; wireless sensor networks; medical applications},
  DOI = {10.1016/j.comcom.2010.06.005},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00490195}
}
%% inria-00597448, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00597448
%%

@article{friggeri:2011:inria-00597448:1,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Cointet, Jean-Philippe and Latapy, Matthieu, Matthieu},
  TITLE = {{A Real-World Spreading Experiment in the Blogosphere}},
  JOURNAL = {{Complex Systems}},
  PUBLISHER = {Complex Systems Publications, Inc.},
  VOLUME = {19},
  NUMBER = {3},
  YEAR = {2011},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00597448}
}
%% inria-00475921, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00475921
%%

@inproceedings{friggeri:2010:inria-00475921:1,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Chelius, Guillaume},
  TITLE = {{Biais dans les mesures obtenues par un r{\'e}seau de capteurs sans fil}},
  BOOKTITLE = {{12{\`e}mes Rencontres Francophones sur les Aspects Algorithmiques de T{\'e}l{\'e}communications (AlgoTel)}},
  YEAR = {2010},
  EDITOR = {Maria Gradinariu Potop-Butucaru and Herv{\'e} Rivano},
  KEYWORDS = {france},
  ADDRESS = {Belle Dune, France},
  MONTH = Jun,
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00475921}
}
%% inria-00587942, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00587942
%%

@inproceedings{friggeri:2011:inria-00587942:1,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Chelius, Guillaume and Fleury, Eric},
  TITLE = {{Communaut{\'e}s : Arr{\^e}tons de ne compter que les ar{\^e}tes}},
  BOOKTITLE = {{13es Rencontres Francophones sur les Aspects Algorithmiques de T{\'e}l{\'e}communications (AlgoTel)}},
  YEAR = {2011},
  EDITOR = {Ducourthial, Bertrand and Felber, Pascal},
  MONTH = Jun,
  KEYWORDS = {france},
  ADDRESS = {Cap Est{\'e}rel, France},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00587942}
}
%% inria-00597446, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00597446
%%

@inproceedings{friggeri:2011:inria-00597446:1,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Chelius, Guillaume and Fleury, Eric},
  TITLE = {{Fellows: Crowd-sourcing the evaluation of an overlapping community model based on the cohesion measure}},
  BOOKTITLE = {{Interdisciplinary Workshop on Information and Decision in Social Networks}},
  YEAR = {2011},
  MONTH = May,
  NOTE = {31 accept{\'e}/140 soumis +250 participants},
  ADDRESS = {Cambridge, {\'E}tats-Unis},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00597446}
}
%% inria-00597447, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00597447
%%

@inproceedings{friggeri:2011:inria-00597447:1,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Chelius, Guillaume and Fleury, Eric},
  TITLE = {{Egomunities, Exploring Socially Cohesive Person-based Communities}},
  BOOKTITLE = {{NetSci 2011 The International School and Conference on Network Science}},
  YEAR = {2011},
  MONTH = Jun,
  ADDRESS = {Budapest, Hongrie},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00597447}
}
%% inria-00619092, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00619092
%%

@inproceedings{friggeri:2011:inria-00619092:1,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Chelius, Guillaume and Fleury, Eric},
  TITLE = {{Triangles to Capture Social Cohesion}},
  BOOKTITLE = {{Third IEEE International Conference on Social Computing}},
  YEAR = {2011},
  MONTH = Sep,
  ADDRESS = {Cambridge, {\'E}tats-Unis},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00619092}
}
%% inria-00626064, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00626064
%%

@inproceedings{friggeri:2011:inria-00626064:1,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Chelius, Guillaume and Fleury, Eric},
  TITLE = {{Fellows: Crowd-sourcing the evaluation of an overlapping community model based on the cohesion measure}},
  BOOKTITLE = {{Complex Dynamics of Human Interactions}},
  YEAR = {2011},
  MONTH = Sep,
  ADDRESS = {Vienna, Autriche},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00626064}
}
%% inria-00507447, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00507447
%%

@inproceedings{lucet:2010:inria-00507447:1,
  AUTHOR = {Lucet, Jean-Christophe and Chelius, Guillaume and Laouenan, C{\'e}dric and Friggeri, Adrien and Veziris, N. and Lepelletier, D. and Abiteboul, D. and Bouvet, Elisabeth and Fleury, Eric and Mentr{\'e}, France},
  TITLE = {{Electronic Sensors for Measuring Interactions between Healthcare Workers (HCWs) and Patients (Pts): the Case of Tuberculosis (TB)}},
  YEAR = {2010},
  MONTH = Sep,
  BOOKTITLE = {{2010 Interscience Conference on Antimicrobial Agents and Chemotherapy}},
  ORGANIZATION = {American Society for Microbiology},
  ADDRESS = {Boston, {\'E}tats-Unis},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00507447}
}
%% inria-00630363, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00630363
%%

@inproceedings{friggeri:2011:inria-00630363:1,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Chelius, Guillaume and Fleury, Eric},
  TITLE = {{Trouver des communaut{\'e}s socialement coh{\'e}sives est NP-dur}},
  YEAR = {2011},
  MONTH = Oct,
  KEYWORDS={france},
  BOOKTITLE = {{13emes journ{\'e}es Graphes et Algorithmes}},
  ADDRESS = {Lyon, France},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00630363}
}
%% inria-00605673, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00605673
%%

@misc{friggeri:2011:inria-00605673:1,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Fleury, Eric},
  TITLE = {{Des triangles pour mesurer la coh{\'e}sion sociale : Fellows, une exp{\'e}rimentation sur Facebook}},
  YEAR = {2011},
  MONTH = Jun,
  KEYWORDS = {france},
  NOTE = {S{\'e}minaire w2s @ La Cantine},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00605673}
}
%% hal-00692548, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/hal-00692548
%%

@techreport{friggeri:2012:hal-00692548:1,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Fleury, Eric},
  TITLE = {{Finding cohesive communities with C³}},
  TYPE = {Rapport de recherche},
  YEAR = {2012},
  MONTH = Apr,
  INSTITUTION = {INRIA},
  NUMBER = {RR-7947},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/hal-00692548}
}
%% inria-00565336, version 2
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00565336
%%

@techreport{friggeri:2011:inria-00565336:2,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Chelius, Guillaume and Fleury, Eric},
  TITLE = {{Egomunities, Exploring Socially Cohesive Person-based Communities}},
  TYPE = {Rapport de recherche},
  YEAR = {2011},
  MONTH = Feb,
  KEYWORDS = {social networks, complex networks, real-world graphs, community detection, overlapping communities, data mining, modelisation},
  INSTITUTION = {INRIA},
  NUMBER = {RR-7535},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00565336}
}
%% inria-00608889, version 1
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00608889
%%

@techreport{friggeri:2011:inria-00608889:1,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Chelius, Guillaume and Fleury, Eric},
  TITLE = {{Triangles to Capture Social Cohesion}},
  TYPE = {Rapport de recherche},
  YEAR = {2011},
  MONTH = Jul,
  INSTITUTION = {INRIA},
  NUMBER = {RR-7686},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00608889}
}
%% inria-00621065, version 2
%% http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00621065
%%

@techreport{friggeri:2011:inria-00621065:2,
  AUTHOR = {Friggeri, Adrien and Fleury, Eric},
  TITLE = {{Maximizing the Cohesion is NP-hard}},
  TYPE = {Rapport de recherche},
  YEAR = {2011},
  MONTH = Sep,
  INSTITUTION = {INRIA},
  NUMBER = {RR-7734},
  URL = {http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00621065}
}

@article{Lucet:2012gl,
author = {Lucet, Jean-Christophe and Laouenan, Cédric and Chelius, Guillaume and Veziris, Nicolas and Lepelletier, Didier and Friggeri, Adrien and Abiteboul, Dominique and Bouvet, Elisabeth and Mentré, France and Fleury, Eric},
title = {{Electronic Sensors for Assessing Interactions between Healthcare Workers and Patients under Airborne Precautions}},
journal = {PLoS ONE},
year = {2012},
volume = {7},
number = {5},
pages = {e37893},
month = may
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here and not in a link (primarily for your question to be of use to others; not to mention Sharelatex requires one to log in). And make it a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) as far as possible.

Comment: @Troy. Thank you for your comment. I revised my question.

Comment: @user2991243 maybe you should cite something? try to add `\cite{*}` after `\section{publications}`

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin I added `\cite{*}
\printbibsection{pai2011enhanced}{pai2011enhanced} `, but it didn't work.

Comment: Other errors: `I found no \citation commands---while reading file cv_file.aux`, `I found no \bibdata command---while reading file cv_me.aux`, and `I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file cv_me.aux`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I do not have the fonts you are using in your resume so I can not test your given code.

But I extracted the part relevant to printing the bibliography and used class `article` to test it.  This is the code I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  style=verbose, 
  maxnames=99, 
  sorting=ydnt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\newcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[%
%     sorting=chronological, 
      type={#1}, 
      title={#2}, 
      heading=subbibliography
    ]
  \end{refsection}
}


\begin{document}

%\printbibsection{article}{article in peer-reviewed journal}
\printbibliography[%
% sorting=chronological, 
  type={article}, 
  title={article in peer-reviewed journal}, 
  heading=subbibliography
]
\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[%
%   sorting=chronological, 
    type=inproceedings, 
    title={international peer-reviewed conferences/proceedings}, 
    notkeyword={france}, 
    heading=subbibliography
  ]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[%
%   sorting=chronological, 
    type=inproceedings, 
    title={local peer-reviewed conferences/proceedings}, 
    keyword={france}, 
    heading=subbibliography
  ]
\end{refsection}
%\printbibsection{misc}{other publications}
%\printbibsection{report}{research reports}

\end{document}
```

I commented option `sorting` for `\printbibliography`, because it throws the warning

```
Package biblatex Warning: sorting option to \printbibliography is no longer supported, use 'sorting' option to \newrefcontext
```

Then I get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Is that what you expect?

If not please explain in your question what you expect to get.  Perhaps you can change the used fonts in the class file to Latin Modern, then others can test the code too ...